# MATLAB's function imfill() causes error

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a binary image (720x1280 logical) that has some holes in it, so I'm using `imfill` to fill it up, however the action fails and I get the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'eml_assert_all_constant'.
Error in iptcheckconn (line 8)
eml_assert_all_constant(varargin{:});
Error in imreconstruct>parseInputs (line 136)
    iptcheckconn(varargin{3},mfilename,'CONN',3);
Error in imreconstruct (line 74)
[marker,mask,conn] = parseInputs(varargin{:});
Error in imfill (line 141)
    I2 = imreconstruct(marker, mask, conn);
```

I've checked other resources, and they suggested that the files `imreconstruct` and `iptcheckconn` might not exist, but they do.
Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Did you recently upgrade MATLAB or the Image Processing Toolbox?

Comment: Not really. I just recently installed the toolbox

Comment: What does `which iptcheckconn` show you?

Comment: the following: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\images\images\eml\iptcheckconn.m`

Comment: Now try `which iptcheckconn -all`. I only get one result showing up for R2016b: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\images\iptutils\iptcheckconn.m`

Comment: I got 2 - what does that mean?
`C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\images\images\eml\iptcheckconn.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\images\iptutils\iptcheckconn.m    % Shadowed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the comments, using [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) shows you the location of the file [`iptcheckconn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/iptcheckconn.html) that gets called. The `-all` option shows you that there are two versions, showing up in these folders for you in R2016a:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\images\images\eml
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\images\iptutils
```

For me, in R2016b, I only see one showing up in the `iptutils` folder. Your problem appears to be that you have some subfolders in the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/) that have been added to your [MATLAB path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-remove-or-reorder-folders-on-the-search-path.html) even though they normally shouldn't be. The `eml` folder does not appear on my MATLAB path, and I don't think it's normally supposed to. I've seen issues like this sometimes appear during installation.

The version of `iptcheckconn` in the first folder is shadowing the version you really want to use in the second folder. You'll want to [remove](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmpath.html) the first folder from the path so MATLAB uses the correct one. Alternatively, you could also leave that folder on the path but just *move it down* on the path list so it shows up *after* the second folder. From the documentation:

> When files with the same name appear in multiple folders on the search path, MATLAB uses the one found in the folder nearest to the top of the search path.