# iptPointerManager error when using roipoly (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, toolbox

I'm trying to use roipoly(I) to allow user selection of a region within an image. When I run the example code from MATLAB documentation:

```
img = imread('eight.tif')
imshow(img)
bw = roipoly(img)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'iptPointerManager'.
```

with several other error lines after, but i'm quite convinced that the one above is the issue.
I have MATLAB R2016a on Windows 7 with image processing toolbox installed and working.

Comment: Try resetting your path `restoredefaultpath`

Comment: I get the feeling this is the same sort of problem as was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45924119/52738), just for a different function.

Comment: Sardar it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the path using `restoredefaultpath` worked.